# Why is Euler's number an uppercase "E" and not a lowercase "e"?

Tags: syntax, language-design

Why is Euler's number an uppercase "E" and not a lowercase "e"?

Isn't Euler's Number normally expressed with a lowercase "e"?

Comment: All MM-defined symbols start with uppercase

Comment: No need to downvote, guys.

Comment: You can also typeset it with Esc + ee + Esc...

Comment: ...or enter `\[ExponentialE]` directly.

Comment: And note that the 'e' you obtain from Esc + ee + Esc or from `\[ExponentialE]` has a doubled stroke on its left, as do the corresponding symbols from `\[ImaginaryI]` and `[\DifferentialD]` -- akin to the "blackboard bold" font commonly used in typesetting mathematical documents (e.g., with LaTeX).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As often happens here, the comment provides the answer, but here's the answer from Stephen Wolfram's book about Mathematica (the second edition of "Mathematica, a System for Doing Mathematics by Computer" which I bought for £0.01 on Amazon):

> Mathematica uses both upper- and lower-case letters. There is a convention that built-in Mathematica objects always have names starting with upper-case (capital) letters. To avoid confusion, you should always choose names for your own variables that start with lower-case letters.

This means that you can use `e`, `i`, `n`, or even `sin` or `pi` for your own variables without conflicting with Mathematica's constants and functions.

Comment: Closed? "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." you're joking, surely... :)

Comment: I agree, your answer clearly involves a fact. Reopened the question. It seemed to be close to being reopened anyway.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, I wouldn't have bothered, but this was the first question I've been able to answer for ages :)

Comment: Just to explain my vote, I saw this from the review page which does not show the answers. So only the question, which was not really a serious/useful one, was shown with 4 close votes already. Also, the comments seemed to have explained it well, so I cast the final vote. Probably wouldn't have voted had I seen your answer, but someone else would've cast the final one :)

Comment: @R.M No worries - I'm just being curmudgeonly today... It wasn't much of a question, true, but then it's no worse than [this one](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/635/definition-of-mma) :)