# Confusing ReplaceRepeated & Hold

Tags: replacement, hold

I've been bootstrapping myself to the very alien world of Mathematica and there came my first WTF moment:

```
RRP[P_, O_, Phi_, L_, M_] :=
  If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}] //. {
    v0 -> {Cos[Phi], Sin[Phi]},
    OP -> P - O,
    l1 -> Dot[OP, v0],
    v1 -> l1*v0,
    d  -> Norm[OP - v1],
    l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]
  };
```

What I wanted to achieve is to recursively apply these rules(which I felt similar to a context-free grammar) to form the desired expression. There was no cyclic dependency in the rules, nor were alternatives, so I kinda expected it to expand correctly. But it didn't!

---

Edit: I'm trying to calculate the position of the internal joint in a planar RRP linkage. Expressed in procedural language it's probably like this(pseudocode):

```js
/* P: position of external R joint
 * O: reference point of P joint
 * Phi: direction of P joint
 * L: length of the R-R bar
 * M: +1/-1
 */
function RRP(P, O, Phi, L, M){
    OP=P-O;
    v0=[cos(Phi), sin(Phi)];
    l1=dot(OP, v0);
    v1=l1*v0;
    d=norm(OP-v1);
    l2=l1+M*sqrt(L^2-d^2);
    if(d<=L) return O+l2*v0;
    else return [];
}
```

---

Since I haven't figured out how to even *debug* here, I tried to output intermediate variables(or non-terminals in CFG terminology):

```
RRP[P_, O_, Phi_, L_, M_] :=
  {d, OP, v1, OP - v1} //. {
    v0 -> {Cos[Phi], Sin[Phi]},
    OP -> P - O,
    l1 -> Dot[OP, v0],
    v1 -> l1*v0,
    d -> Norm[OP - v1],
    l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]
    };
RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1]
```

And it gave me this:

```
{{6, Sqrt[26]}, {-5, 1}, {-5, 0}, {{0, -5}, {6, 1}}}
```

`OP` and `v1` were as expected. But WTF was `OP-v1`? A *Matrix*?

---

I figure I can't do much with `OP` so I tried manually substituting `v1` in the `d->` rule:

```
RRP[P_, O_, Phi_, L_, M_] :=
  {d, OP, v1, OP - l1*v0} //. {
    v0 -> {Cos[Phi], Sin[Phi]},
    OP -> P - O,
    l1 -> Dot[OP, v0],
    v1 -> l1*v0,
    d -> Norm[OP - l1*v0],
    l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]
  };
RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1]
```

Now it gives me the correct answer:

```
{1, {-5, 1}, {-5, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

---

So now I'm VERY confused about this,

I don't even know if I'm following the proper/idiomatic way of constructing complex functions, thanks to the arcane Help that came with Mathematica... Could anyone please either point out the problem, or kindly enlighten me on how I could construct a equivalent function in "The Mathematica Way"?

---

EDIT: After some lookup I figured out that the evaluation order for `OP - v1` was to blame. So I added `Hold[]` around the culprit and `//ReleaseHold` the whole thing after `//.` finishes building the expression. It works:

```
RRP[P_, O_, \[Phi]_, L_, M_] := (
    If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}] //. {
      v0 -> {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]},
      OP -> P - O,
      l1 -> Dot[OP, v0],
      v1 -> l1*v0,
      d -> Norm[Hold[OP - v1]],
      l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]
    }) // ReleaseHold;
RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1]
```

But I am still confused:

Could I know where I need `Hold[]` when I *write* the code, not as a workaround after I found out something wrong with it?

Comment: please delete the SO version. It is not a good idea to cross post

Comment: Please also explain a bit of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @rm-rf okay I'm not quite familiar with the procedures here... I'll do right away

Comment: @Mr.Wizard should I write the expression in a procedural form(C-like)?

Comment: That might help.

Comment: Better: why not describe the problem you're trying to solve in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M. I think replacing all rules to assignments will do. I'm basically just simulating "intermediate variables" I got so used to before the transition to Mathematica.

Comment: BTW: using `O` as a variable is a bad idea here, since it's a protected symbol in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm not seeing the recursive (or replace *repeated*) nature in your pseudocode.  I am I overlooking something?

Comment: @J.M. Oops I didn't know it. Thanks for the tip(although it probably didn't matter in this example)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Umm... I think the order of replacement might matter if I just apply it once?

Comment: @J.M. I don't see the problem in using `O` here as it is used as a pattern name, not a free variable.  Of course elsewhere it should be avoided.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, true, it gets replaced. I still don't think it's a good way to go about things tho...

Comment: @J.M. And yes--since I'm just starting, I am very concerned with writing proper, idiomatic code that resemble mathematical/pragmatic notation as much as possible...

Comment: I'm guessing that you shouldn't use the single letter variable names C, D, E, I, K, N, or O. Best stick to lower-case for everything, as per [Mr Wolfram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/why-is-eulers-number-an-uppercase-e-and-not-a-lowercase-e)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I can't follow your code, I guess your problem is caused by the fact that you get evaluation in between individual replacements, and the fact that `Listable` functions of several arguments (which includes operators like `+` and `*`) have quite peculiar behaviour. The fact that you get a matrix instead of a vector, as well as the fact that you can avoid it with a `Hold` point into this direction.

## The problem with `Listable` functions and replacement

Consider the following two expressions

```
{1, 2} + 3
(*
==> {4, 5}
*)
{1, 2} + {3, 4}
(*
==> {4, 6}
*)
```

This is caused by the following rule:

- If both arguments are lists, the operation is applied to pairs of corresponding elements.
- If only one element is a list, then operation is applied to the elements of that list and the other argument.

Now consider the following expression:

```
{1, 2} + x
(*
==> {1 + x, 2 + x}
*)
```

Since `x` is not a list, the second bullet point above is used. This gives surprises if you replace `x` with a list:

```
{1, 2} + x /. x -> {3, 4}
(*
==> {{4, 5}, {5, 6}}
*)
```

This is because `/.` *first* evaluates the left hand side, and only *then* applies the rule. Therefore `{1, 2} + x /. x -> {3, 4}` first evaluates, according to the second bullet point, to `{1 + x, 2 + x} /. x -> {3, 4}` and only then does the replacement, leading to `{1 + {3, 4}, 2 + {3, 4}}` where for the individual sums again the second bullet point rule applies, to give `{{1+3, 1+4}, {2+3, 2+4}}` which gives the result above. Note how in the process, you've generated a matrix from your vectors.

## Interaction with `//.`

Now consider the following two expressions:

```
x + y //. {x -> {1,2}, y -> {3,4}}
(*
==> {4, 6}
*)
x + y //. {x -> {1,2}, y -> z, z -> {3,4}}
(*
==> {{4, 5}, {5, 6}}
*)
```

As you see, the first one gives the expected expression, while the second one doesn't, despite the fact that looking at the replacements, it apparently should be equivalent.

The reason for the difference is that after each round of replacement, the expression is evaluated again, before the next round of replacements is done. So in the first case, after replacing `x` and `y`, you end up with `{1, 2} + {3, 4}` which evaluates to `{4, 6}` whithout any further replacements. However in the second case, the first round of replacement leaves you with `{1, 2} + z` which, as described above, will evaluate to `{1 + z, 2 + z}`, and *that* is what the second round of replacements acts on, replacing `z` with `{3, 4}`.

## Solution

If you just don't want to evaluate anything before all replacement rules have been applied, just wrap the original expression in `Hold` and the whole expression including the replacement rules in `ReleaseHold`:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[x + y] //. {x -> {1,2}, y -> z, z -> {3,4}}]
(*
==> {4, 6}
*)
```

If you want the original expression to be evaluated *just once* before applying the rules, one trick is to put it in an extra initial rule which is not deferred (i.e. `->`, not `:>`):

```
f[z] = x;
ReleaseHold[Hold[initial] //.
  {initial -> f[z] + y, x -> {1,2}, y -> z, z -> {3,4}}]
(*
==> {4, 6}
*)
```

Without this initial rule trick you'd get

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[f[z] + y] //. {x -> {1,2}, y -> z, z -> {3,4}}]
(*
==> {3 + f[{3, 4}], 4 + f[{3, 4}]}
*)
```

because `z` would be replaced before `f` got applied on it.

Comment: Yes exactly(although I figured out the vector-scalar relationship earlier myself earlier). You made it clear without doubt.

Answer (score 2):

After staring at this for a bit I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure what I have to say will be satisfactory.  It seems that you are giving a series of transformation rules that you want to be carried out in isolation, that is apart from the normal evaluation process.  For this reason `Hold` is naturally needed, and it should wrap the entire expression, not just one element.

```
RRP[P_, O_, Phi_, L_, M_] :=
 ReleaseHold[
  Hold[If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}]] //.
   {v0 -> {Cos[Phi], Sin[Phi]},
    OP -> P - O,
    l1 -> Dot[OP, v0],
    v1 -> l1*v0,
    d -> Norm[OP - v1],
    l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]}
 ]
```

If this technique does not work in another case of the same method please post that case as well.

Of course it's probably easier in this case just to translate your pseudocode literally:

```
RRP[P_, O_, Phi_, L_, M_] :=
 Module[{OP, l1, l2, v0, v1, d},
  OP = P - O;
  v0 = {Cos[Phi], Sin[Phi]};
  l1 = OP.v0;
  v1 = l1*v0;
  d = Norm[OP - v1];
  l2 = l1 + M*Sqrt[L^2 - d^2];
  If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}]
 ]

RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1]
```

> ```
> {1, 0}
> ```

---

I don't believe I properly understand your program yet, but I'll show you how I might go about visualizing what is taking place.

We can use `FixedPointList` and `/.` in place of `//.`, which will allow us to keep the steps of evaluation.  Using that we can compare the versions with and without Hold:

```
ClearAll[RRP]

RRP[P_, O_, \[Phi]_, L_, M_] := 
  FixedPointList[# /. {v0 -> {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, OP -> P - O, 
       l1 -> Dot[OP, v0], v1 -> l1*v0, d -> Norm[Hold[OP - v1]], 
       l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]} &, If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}]] // 
   ReleaseHold

RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1] // Column
```

Output:

```
If[d<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+l2 v0,{}]

If[Norm[OP-v1]<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-d^2]+l1) {1,0},{}]

If[Sqrt[Abs[-5-l1 v0]^2+Abs[1-l1 v0]^2]<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[OP-v1]^2]+OP.v0) {1,0},{}]

If[Sqrt[1+Abs[-5-OP.v0]^2]<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[{-5,1}-l1 v0]^2]+{-5,1}.{1,0}) {1,0},{}]

{Sqrt[1-Abs[-5-OP.v0]^2],0}

{1,0}

{1,0}
```

Now without Hold:

```
ClearAll[RRP]

RRP[P_, O_, \[Phi]_, L_, M_] := 
 FixedPointList[# /. {v0 -> {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]]}, OP -> P - O, 
     l1 -> Dot[OP, v0], v1 -> l1*v0, d -> Norm[OP - v1], 
     l2 -> l1 + M Sqrt[L^2 - d^2]} &, If[d <= L, O + l2*v0, {}]]

RRP[{0, 1}, {5, 0}, 0, Sqrt[2], 1] // Column
```

Output:

```
If[d<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+l2 v0,{}]

If[Norm[OP-v1]<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-d^2]+l1) {1,0},{}]

If[Sqrt[Abs[-5-l1 v0]^2+Abs[1-l1 v0]^2]<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[OP-v1]^2]+OP.v0) {1,0},{}]

If[{Sqrt[Abs[-5-OP.v0]^2+Abs[1-OP.v0]^2],Sqrt[26]}<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[{-5,1}-l1 v0]^2]+{-5,1}.{1,0}) {1,0},{}]

If[{6,Sqrt[26]}<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[{-5,1}-OP.v0 {1,0}]^2]+{-5,1}.{1,0}) {1,0},{}]

If[{6,Sqrt[26]}<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[{-5,1}-{-5,1}.{1,0} {1,0}]^2]+{-5,1}.{1,0}) {1,0},{}]

If[{6,Sqrt[26]}<=Sqrt[2],{5,0}+(Sqrt[2-Norm[{-5,1}-{-5,1}.{1,0} {1,0}]^2]+{-5,1}.{1,0}) {1,0},{}]
```

Perhaps you can see from this where things go wrong.

Comment: As I told the OP, using the protected symbol `O` as an argument might not be the best idea...

Comment: @J.M. I am not suggesting it!  I am trying to show a method of debugging; I don't what to change the code more than necessary.

Comment: Yes I have already figured out that `OP-v1` expanded first to `{_,_}-v1` then `{_-v1,_-v1}`, before `v1` even got expanded, where the `-` was understood as operation between vector and scalar, all while I really mean to "expand both `OP` and `v1` before applying the vector difference"...

Comment: Hmm I think I get the idea about how and why `Hold[]` works now. I don't really like the idea of injecting syntactic noise into mathematical notation, so could you please suggest a way I could rewrite the code in a more idiomatic way?

Comment: @smilekzs I just added a brief statement at the top of this answer.  Please review it and tell me if you think I'm understanding the question better now or if it eludes me.

Comment: Oh... So I could just write procedural code as I'm used to. I thought it has to be purely functional!

Comment: @smilekzs The method you came up with to work around that nonexistent problem is actually quite nice!  While *Mathematica* has many Functional tools, it is a multi-paradigm language that can be used in most programming styles.  [Some perform better than others though.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

Comment: @smile: "I could just write procedural code as I'm used to." - you certainly can; as the Wizard says, tho, since *Mathematica* supports a number of paradigms, it's still useful to see if a different paradigm might give rise to a better expression of your algorithm.